# what causes my app crashing when coming back to screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have listing of videos in UITableView which uses custom class. This is tabbar application. When I scroll down to 8th video, and go to next screen and when I come back to video listing screen, the app crashes. I tried to debug but cannot figure out the issue. This is what I get from debugger.

```
2016-06-08 12:47:46.919 Votocast[2283:453809] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108ba9d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a7f9deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108a87804 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
    3   Votocast                            0x0000000107dfd4de -[HomeView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 958
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b6914f4 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 766
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b69162c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b665c8a -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2799
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b69a686 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b681344 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 224
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b5ee980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ff1c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109fe608e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109fe5f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109fda3c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a008086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b52e72e _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7135
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108acf301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108ac522c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108ac46e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108ac40f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d4ebad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010b533f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  Votocast                            0x0000000107e48d8f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cc0792d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

In viewWillAppear, I remove all objects from this array and call webservice. But before I get response from webservice, app crashes to a line in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Your little help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I have noticed that app only crashes when my tableview decelerationrate and I go to next screen and comeback to video listing screen. I have not done any type of code regarding decelerationration.

Comment: your array is empty thats'y its crashing. Try to put the value in array in below method-
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
it may help you.

Comment: ohh...your array is not getting maintain. Handle it within code. Try to add all objects in array in ViewDidLoad. Also check action you are taking with array in ViewWill/DidDisappear.

Comment: What value are you returning from `numberOfRowsInSection`?  When you remove all the array values, do you immediately call `reloadData` on your tableview?

Comment: you can say which place to crash your app.. and you can not found that place???

Comment: Give your code for fixing quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Clear all the object From Array in `viewWillAppear` Method But, do you Reload the tableview after that.

because this can cause the crash. you remove all the object but tableview tries to goto the last scrolled index. so it cause the crash.

Hope this will help You.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly your datasource delegate isn't working properly. If you empty an array that is used by the datasource, then you must call reloadData. And when you get new data, you call reloadData again.

However, you shouldn't refresh data that way. You should display the old data until new data arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I fixed it. I actually was allocating array in viewDidLoad and was just removing objects from that array in viewWillAppear. So I preserve my data and not calling webservice in viewWillAppear.